# Crear un juego en vista isométrica en Pyglet

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un trabajillo de subida de nota para la uni. Yo le pregunté al profesor si estaba bien crear un pequeño juego con Pyglet, y me respondió que sí. La cuestión es, me gustaría hacer un juego con vista isométrica, pero no se cómo crear el mapa. De momento, este es mi código:

```
import pyglet

pyglet.resource.path = ['./assets']
pyglet.resource.reindex()

window = pyglet.window.Window(caption='Petrol Tycoon', visible=False, fullscreen=True)

window.set_mouse_cursor(window.get_system_mouse_cursor(window.CURSOR_CROSSHAIR))

main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

cube_image = pyglet.resource.image("cube2.png")
cube_image.anchor_x = cube_image.width // 2
cube_image.anchor_y = cube_image.height // 2

cubes = []

map_data = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

for i in range(len(map_data)):
    for j in range(len(map_data[i]), 0, -1):
        cubes.append(
            pyglet.sprite.Sprite(cube_image,
                                 batch=main_batch,
                                 x=(j * cube_image.width / 2) + (i * cube_image.width / 2),
                                 y=(i * cube_image.height / 2) + (j * cube_image.height / 2)
                                 )
                    )


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

    main_batch.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.set_visible()

    pyglet.app.run()
```

Nota: el código proviene de esta pregunta (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629885/how-to-render-an-isometric-tile-based-world-in-python).

El problema es, al ejecutarlo no sale como esperaba (sale así: [image: Vista del juego]). No entiendo el porqué, la verdad. Me gustaría que alguien me corrigiera el código.

Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda, ya que me podeís salvar la asignatura. Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cómo querrías que te saliera? Entiendo que el problema es que las caras de algunos cubos aparecen "por delante" de otros cuando no debería ser así ¿cierto? Me temo que eso se debe al orden en que pintas los cubos. Deberías tenerlos ordenados de más lejano a más cercano, para pintarlos en ese orden. No sé si es a ésto a lo que te referías o hay algún problema más

Comment: @abulafia Sí, eso es justo a lo que me refería. Pero aparte de eso, ni siquiera se pintan formando una rejilla, sino que se pintan formando otra cosa.

Comment: Por pura curiosidad, ¿Qué estudias? ¿Algo relacionado con artes gráficas, animación, cine? ¿O algo técnico, como ingeniería, economía, medicina ...?

Comment: @CandidMoe Estoy estudiando Ingeniería Informática, y este año tocaba Python. Y pensé que hacer un pequeño juego estaría bien, después de un año de ese Python que odio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad, reescribir el código así sería correcto.

```
import pyglet

pyglet.resource.path = ['./assets']
pyglet.resource.reindex()

window = pyglet.window.Window(caption='Petrol Tycoon', visible=False, fullscreen=True)

window.set_mouse_cursor(window.get_system_mouse_cursor(window.CURSOR_CROSSHAIR))

main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

cube_image = pyglet.resource.image("cube2.png")
cube_image.anchor_x = cube_image.width // 2
cube_image.anchor_y = cube_image.height // 2

cubes = []

def drawline(data: list, x: int, y: int):
    for n in data:
        cubes.append(pyglet.sprite.Sprite(cube_image, batch=main_batch, x=x, y=y, subpixel=True))
        x += cube_image.width / 2
        y -= cube_image.height / 4


x = window.width / 2
y = window.height / 2
for r in cubes_data:
    drawline(r, x, y)
    x -= cube_image.width / 2
    y -= cube_image.height / 4


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

    main_batch.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.set_visible()

    pyglet.app.run()
```